# Telerik RadGrid Insert Fails - Cannot enter null value

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a telerik `RadGrid`, using an `SqlDataSource`. 
I've set the parameteres for insert/select/update statements etc, but upon trying to add a new record, I recieve this error...

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'fld_title', table 'DB_Tests.dbo.tbl_posts'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

**edit**

My question was perhaps unclear at first - I don't actually want to enter a null value into the database, I want to add the data entered using the `add new record` command option. 
So my question is ... 
 **Why am I getting null values, rather than the data I've entered?**

Here is my full Code.

```
<telerik:RadGrid id="pageGrid" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        DataSourceID="pageSrc"
        AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="false"
        AutoGenerateEditColumn="true"
        AllowAutomaticInserts="true"
        AllowAutomaticUpdates="true"
        BackColor="#d9e8ff"
        BorderColor="#000066"



        >
        <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top">

            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_title" HeaderText="Title" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_short_desc" HeaderText="Short Description" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_text" HeaderText="Text" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_cat" HeaderText="Category" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_live" HeaderText="Live?" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>

        </MasterTableView>




 </telerik:RadGrid>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="pageSrc" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:localTest %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM tbl_posts WHERE pk_ID = @pk_ID"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbl_posts] VALUES (@title, @short_desc, @text, @cat, @live)"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [pk_ID], [fld_title], [fld_short_desc], [fld_text], [fld_cat] , fld_live FROM [tbl_posts]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_posts] SET [fld_title] = @title, [fld_short_desc] = @short_desc, [fld_text] = @text, [fld_cat] = @cat, [fld_live] = @live WHERE [pk_ID] = @pk_ID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="pk_ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="pk_ID" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="short_desc" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="cat" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="live" Type="Boolean" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="pk_ID" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="title" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="short_desc" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="cat" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="live" Type="Boolean" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"></asp:Parameter>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**edit** 
I've read other questions where people have similar issues, however they were all resolved by configuring the parameters correctly, and I believe that mine are.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add validation and error handing through the ItemInserted and InsertCommand events: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/automatic-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx
The grid cannot validate missing values for you, so you have to handle this.

To further this - consider creating the data source operations yourself through the grid events, so you can easily validate things, instead of using automated operations: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/manual-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx

Also, you can define the edit form yourself, so you can use more compex controls and add client-side validation to prevent unneeded postbacks: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/form-template-update/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You UniqueName property has to be the same value as the parameter name.

```
 <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_title" UniqueName="title" HeaderText="Title" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_short_desc" UniqueName="short_desc" HeaderText="Short Description" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_text" UniqueName="text" HeaderText="Text" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_cat" UniqueName="cat" HeaderText="Category" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataField="fld_live" UniqueName="live" HeaderText="Live?" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#ff66ff"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
```

seems like you are also missing the PK_ID field that you are using as a parameter. You need to add that GridBoundColumn in order for the CRUD operations to find it, then make sure the UniqueName property reflects the parameter name.

Answer (score -3):

Go to SQL Server Management and select that table and allow nulls. This will solve the problem.

Comment: this allows an insert to be made to the database, but as I suspected before (which is why I didn't try this at first), its is just a record full of nulls in the database, instead of the data entered in the add new record field.